# ustring - an inplace replacement of std::string/std::wstring?

Tags: c++, string, unicode

A continuation on [C++ and UTF8 - Why not just replace ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400535/c-and-utf8-why-not-just-replace-ascii)

Why is there no `std::ustring` which could replace both `std::string`, `std::wstring` in new applications?

Of course with corresponding support in the standard library. Similarly to how `boost::filesystem3::path` doesn't care about string representation and works with both `std::string` and `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you replace anything?

`string` and `wstring` are the string classes corresponding to `char` and `wchar_t`, which in the context of interfacing with the environment are meant to carry data encoded in, respectively, "the system's narrow-multibyte representation" and fixed-width in "the system's encoding".

On the other hand, `u8`/`u`/`U`, as well as `char16_t` and `char32_t`, as well as the corresponding string classes, are intended for the storage of Unicode codepoint sequences encoded in UTF-8/16/32.

The latter is a separate problem domain from the former. The standard doesn't contain a mechanism to bridge the two domains (and a library such as `iconv()` is typically required to make this bridge portable, e.g. by transcoding WCHAR_T/UTF-32).

Here's my standard list of related questions: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c0x), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562609/what-does-cuchar-provide-and-where-is-it-documented)

Answer (score 2):

There's `std::u16string` and `std::u32string`. Standard libraries where you might want to use these, e.g. to name a file to open with fstream, aren't going to be changed to use these because they really can't. For example some platforms take an almost arbitrary byte string to name a file to open, with no specified encoding. Having to run that through a string with a specific encoding would break things and be incompatible.

Comment: These are available only in `C++11`/`C++0x`, which not all compilers or OSes fully support yet.